# Bundling gradle dependencies with aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have a project **project A**  that has these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:24.0.0'
    compile ('com.hannesdorfmann.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'){
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.2'
    compile 'xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
//    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.3'
    compile files('libs/jsevaluator.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-7.0.2.jar')
    compile project(':zoneOrchestra')
    compile project(':scrambledkeyboard')
    compile project(':datelibrary')
    compile project(':phoneNumberValidator')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':inputtypepicker')
    compile project(':pagerIndicator')
    compile project(':persistentSearch')
    compile('com.github.KingsMentor:IntentManip:v1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.8.0@aar')
            {
                transitive = true;
            }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

the project is bundle to **project.aar** , which should serve as a dependency to other projects.

The problem is, when **project.aar** is added to another project, it is unable to build. It requires it's dependencies which for some reasons are not bundled with it.

How do I make sure these dependencies are bundled along with the .aar file?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך , had issues implementing it with flavors.